# How do I update multiple tables with multiple where clauses in one query

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-update, multiple-tables

Is there a way to do multiple updates with one sql query?

Something like:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = Expression1 WHERE Conditions 1
SET Column2 = Expression2 WHERE Conditions 2
SET Column3 = Expression3 WHERE Conditions 3
...;
```

Thank you!

Comment: A DML statement can only effect 1 object (i.e. a `TABLE`) at a time, not multiple. If you need to `UPDATE` *x* number of tables, you need to issue *x* number of `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like an anti pattern, but, syntactically, you can do it using [Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET 
  Column1 = ( case when condition1 then Expression1 else Column1 end  ),
  Column2 = ( case when condition2 then Expression2 else Column2 end  )
```

By the way, I guess you mixed *"multiple tables"* by *"multiple columns"*.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**.